# Каким образом лучше хранить и обрабатывать данные получаемые парсингом?

Tags: парсер, архитектура

Есть проект который является, грубо говоря, аггрегатором.
Суть в том, что с различных ресурсов я с помощью парсинга собираю необходимые данные,  и предоставляю их пользователю в удобном формате. Далее, уже в моём проекте пользователь может совершать необходимые ему манипуляции с этими данными.
Действия пользователей необходимо логгировать для сохранения статистики. Следуя из этого, как я понимаю, мне в любом случае придётся хранить эти данные в БД.

У меня есть несколько вариантов как это можно реализовать: 
при каждом запросе пользователя данные парсятся и записываются в БД - тогда данные в БД всегда будут актуальны. Но получается в таком случае будет большая нагрузка на БД, да и на ресурсы с которых парсится инфа будет лететь слишком много запросов.

Второй вариант - парсить данные по крону и записывать их в БД, скажем раз в час. Но в таком случае есть вероятность(она маленькая, но она есть) что пользователь получит неактуальные данные.

Как бы вы решали эту задачу? Может есть еще какие то варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Спарсить данные при каждом запросе пользователя - плохая идея точно, пользователей может быть много, а парсинг занять значительное время.

Можно сделать по крону, договорившись с пользователями, как часто вызывать скрипт парсинга, насколько свежие данные им нужны, раз в в 20 минут, раз в 15 и т. д. Причем нужно запоминать, что вы парсили до этого, например дату или заголовок последнего спарсенногго материала и при следующей итерации спарсить только новые данные.

Наконец, можно сделать фоновую задачу, например при помощи gearman, если у вас php, скрипт который будет постоянно крутиться в фоне и парсить по мере незанятости вашего сервера.